# No Module Named Pandas in VS 2015

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing this script.

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
import urllib
web = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'

urlToVisit = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/EURUSD=X/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
with urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit) as response:
    sourcePage = response.read().decode()
df = pd.read_csv(sourcePage, skiprows=17, header=None)
df.head()
```

[image]

I'm running this in Visual Studio 2015.  I really think this should work, but VS seems to think Pandas is not installed.  It is definitely installed.  Am I missing something?  Maybe there is some kind of dependency or reference missing?  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Even if it is installed, Visual Studio can't see it for some reason. I recommend you use something a bit lighter weight such as the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) Python distribution. It comes with pandas and many other data analysis modules pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by running in cmd:

```
pip install pandas
```

Make sure you have pip path added to your environmental variables.
You should also add python path to environmental variables.
In my case the path is like this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32;C:\Users\ USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts;
```

Answer (score 0):

install Anaconda and then go to Project Properties in Visual Studio and tell it to use Anaconda as its interpreter.